# Can't Upload Images to iOS SImulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, photos

So I'm trying to put some images onto my iOS simulator (from Xcode 5) and it's not working. I know how to do it by dragging the files across and it loading up safari etc. However everytime I do it it says file does not exist at location, null pointer. I also noticed when I load the photos app from within the simulator it shows nothing but a white screen. I've tried resetting the settings on my simulator but it has no affect. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you drag the image into the simulator and it appears in Safari, are you then saving the images from Safari to the photo library? You didn't mention if you were saving them or not.

Comment: Are you maybe using Xcode 6 or Beta simulator?

Comment: Hey, no I can't save the image because it doesn't even appear, it just says "No file exists at that address (Null)." Oh and no I'm just using Xcode 5 to develop at the moment.